# How to group data from 26th of a month to 25th of the next month using postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, date, monthcalendar

I want to define the start of a “month” as the 26<sup>th</sup> day of the previous calendar month (and of course ending on 25<sup>th</sup>).

How can I group by this definition of month using `date_trunc()`?

Answer (score 0):

This expression gives the month you want:

```
date_trunc(
  'month',
  date_add(
    day, 
    case
      when extract(day from date) > 25 then 7
      else 0
    end),
    my_date_col
  )
)
```

Select it and group by it.

The logic is: If the day of the month is greater than 25, then add some days to bump it into the next month before truncating it to the month.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an INTERVAL to calculate the correct dates. Here an example using generate_series():

```
SELECT  d::date as reference_date
    ,   (d + interval '25 days')::date AS first_day
    ,   (d + interval '1 month' + interval '24 days')::date as last_day
FROM    generate_series('2020-01-01'::timestamp, '2021-01-01'::timestamp, '1 month') g(d);
```